# calculating volatility of return at end of each month using 1 year window

Tags: r, rstudio, xts, zoo, quantmod

I am dealing with a time series of stock returns. The data include thousands of stocks and daily returns of each stock from 1985-2010. There are missing returns due to trading suspension. For each stock, I am trying to calculate moving volatility of returns at end of each month(the last trading day of each month in the dataset) using previous one year returns. I have some data:

```
         date name   return
   1985-01-01    A   -0.044
   1985-01-01    C    0.038
   1985-01-02    A    0.041
   1985-01-02    B   -0.005
   1985-01-02    C   -0.052
   1985-01-03    B    0.018
   1985-01-03    C   -0.034
```

Note that company B did not trade on 1985-01-01, so there is no return data on that day. I have looked up some useful packages such as TTR, zoo, xts. However, all functions need to input the number of period per year, which is different in each stock. My vague idea is to first use split in xts to split data by company names, then apply endpoints function to find the last day of each month. I am stuck there. Since I have a large dataset, I prefer some methods fast. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. What is "moving volatility"? From your description, I would guess that this is the percentage change in the stock's price from exactly one year ago? You want to calculate this value for every stock at each month-end, but some stocks have missing values. So you want to a) impute missing values and b) calculate year-ago changes in each stock's value?

Comment: @jdobres sorry I did not phrase the question quite clear. I am trying to calculate volatility of returns in one year period. Normally, there should be 252 observations in one year. But there are some miss values. What I want is take all the values in one year period and calculate volatility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and also assume each date appears in at least one stock (but need not appear in any particular stock).  252 is usually used for a year which is likely close enough for most uses; however, given the length of the data in the question we use 2 for this example:

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, split = "name")
r <- rollapplyr(z, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
aggregate(r, as.yearmon, tail, 1)
##           A          B          C
## Jan 1985 NA 0.01626346 0.01272792
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
         date name   return
   1985-01-01    A   -0.044
   1985-01-01    C    0.038
   1985-01-02    A    0.041
   1985-01-02    B   -0.005
   1985-01-02    C   -0.052
   1985-01-03    B    0.018
   1985-01-03    C   -0.034"

library(zoo)
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I find number of observations in a one year window, at the end of each month?

Comment: As stated 252 is normally used.

Comment: got it. Another question is how can I get the correct return data. For example, I have returns of a stock from Jan 2017 to Dec 2018. I would like to calculate one year volatility of returns in June 2018. I will take all returns from July 1, 2017 to June 30, 2018. Then apply sd function. Next, I continue this procedure to July 2018 and so on. Is this a quicker way to do this ?

Comment: Have added to answer.

Comment: Using rollapplyr is a smart way to deal with miss values. But what if I have only one stock? Is there any alternative way of doing it to avoid disappear of date ? Also, since I have a really large dataset, rolling on each day and only use variance at end of each month produces a lot of unused data. Is there another way to overcome it? Thank you!

Comment: Merge it with a zoo width series having every day and then use rollapply.  In that case use 365 in rollapply since you will have non-business days as well.   `m <- merge(z$A, zoo(, seq(min(time(z$A)), max(time(z$A)), "day"))); rollapply(m, 365, sd, na.rm = TRUE)`  This will be slightly off for leap years but it is probably close enough.